# Selection of days in which one hour meets the condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with this structure (real data is more complicated):

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1 odczyt.2
'2023-08-14 00:00:00'   362 1.5
'2023-08-14 23:00:00'   633 4.3
'2023-08-15 05:00:00'   224 1.6
'2023-08-15 23:00:00'   445 5.6
'2023-08-16 00:00:00'   182 1.5
'2023-08-16 23:00:00'   493 4.3
'2023-08-17 05:00:00'   434 1.6
'2023-08-17 23:00:00'   485 5.6
'2023-08-18 00:00:00'   686 1.5
'2023-08-18 23:00:00'   487 6.8
'2023-08-19 00:00:00'   566 1.5
'2023-08-19 05:00:00'   278 7.9
'2023-08-19 17:00:00'   561 11.5
'2023-08-19 18:00:00'   365 8.5
'2023-08-19 22:00:00'   170 1.8
'2023-08-19 23:00:00'   456 6.6
'2023-08-20 00:00:00'   498 1.5
'2023-08-20 03:00:00'   961 1.54
'2023-08-20 05:00:00'   397 1.6
'2023-08-20 19:00:00'   532 6.6
'2023-08-20 23:00:00'   493 3.8
'2023-08-21 01:00:00'   441 9.2
'2023-08-21 07:00:00'   793 8.5
'2023-08-21 13:00:00'   395 5.5", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(DT))
```

I am selecting 3 hours for which "odczyt.1" has the maximum value (I sort "odczyt.1" from the largest values and select the 3 largest values). I leave the days in which these hours occurred and delete the rest of the lines.
For the given data these are:

2023-08-20 03:00:00 (961)

2023-08-21 07:00:00 (793)

2023-08-18 00:00:00 (686)

therefore the expected result is:

```
> df1
                    DT odczyt.1 odczyt.2
1  2023-08-18 00:00:00      686     1.50
2  2023-08-18 23:00:00      487     6.80
3  2023-08-20 00:00:00      498     1.50
4  2023-08-20 03:00:00      961     1.54
5  2023-08-20 05:00:00      397     1.60
6  2023-08-20 19:00:00      532     6.60
7  2023-08-20 23:00:00      493     3.80
8  2023-08-21 01:00:00      441     9.20
9  2023-08-21 07:00:00      793     8.50
10 2023-08-21 13:00:00      395     5.50
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that since `odczyt` is Polish for "reading", that your `reading 1` mention is really `odczyt.1`?

Comment: (Sorry, I don't speak Polish but translate.google.com suggested that to me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought:

```r
df1 |>
  mutate(
    day = as.Date(trunc(DT)),
    rnk = rank(-odczyt.1, ties="first")
  ) |>
  filter(.by = day, any(rnk <= 3))
#                     DT odczyt.1 odczyt.2        day rnk
# 1  2023-08-18 00:00:00      686     1.50 2023-08-18   3
# 2  2023-08-18 23:00:00      487     6.80 2023-08-18  11
# 3  2023-08-20 00:00:00      498     1.50 2023-08-20   8
# 4  2023-08-20 03:00:00      961     1.54 2023-08-20   1
# 5  2023-08-20 05:00:00      397     1.60 2023-08-20  17
# 6  2023-08-20 19:00:00      532     6.60 2023-08-20   7
# 7  2023-08-20 23:00:00      493     3.80 2023-08-20  10
# 8  2023-08-21 01:00:00      441     9.20 2023-08-21  15
# 9  2023-08-21 07:00:00      793     8.50 2023-08-21   2
# 10 2023-08-21 13:00:00      395     5.50 2023-08-21  18
```

Comment: It works, although exactly the opposite - the days in which the maximum values occurred are removed

Comment: Oops, my bad, ranked the wrong way. See my edit (going negative on the rank). @GrBa

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
result <- df1 %>% 
  arrange(desc(odczyt.1)) %>%   # i had this changed to read1 before
  .[lubridate::day(.$DT) %in% lubridate::day(.$DT[1:3]), ] %>% 
  arrange(DT) %>% 
  data.table()

result

                    DT odczyt.1 odczyt.2
1  2023-08-18 00:00:00      686     1.50
2  2023-08-18 23:00:00      487     6.80
3  2023-08-20 00:00:00      498     1.50
4  2023-08-20 03:00:00      961     1.54
5  2023-08-20 05:00:00      397     1.60
6  2023-08-20 19:00:00      532     6.60
7  2023-08-20 23:00:00      493     3.80
8  2023-08-21 01:00:00      441     9.20
9  2023-08-21 07:00:00      793     8.50
10 2023-08-21 13:00:00      395     5.50
```

Comment: Why are you using `.$` inside `desc`? (Why did you rename the OP's variables?)

Comment: @r2evans I renamed them according to the original post in which OP translated `odczyt.1` to `read1`. As for the `.$` its because  I'm clumsy with data.table indexing...  - changed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit complicated way of doing this, but it works.

```
sorted_df1 <- df1[order(-df1$odczyt.1), ]
sorted_df1
selected_rows <- sorted_df1[1:3]
selected_dates <- as.Date(selected_rows$DT[1:3])
rd_selected_dates <- floor_date(selected_dates, "day")
rd_selected_dates 
desired_rows <- df1[as.Date(df1$DT) == as.Date(rd_selected_dates[1]) | 
as.Date(df1$DT) == as.Date(rd_selected_dates[2]) | as.Date(df1$DT) == 
as.Date(rd_selected_dates[3]), ]
desired_rows
```

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TZtM.png)